# How do I avoid "variable may not have been initialized" when referencing a JavaScript parent object?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, warnings

I know there are a lot of "how do I avoid this warning" questions, but it looks like mine is the first specific to JavaScript.  In this case, I want to reference *the thing I'm initializing* inside its own declaration, like so:

```
var foo = new Foo({
  bar: new Bar({
    x: function(){
      doStuff(foo);
    }
  });
});
```

(If this looks familiar, maybe you've used ExtJS before -- this is how most of their stuff is built.)

When I call `foo.bar.x()`, I want to point back to the Foo (`foo`) that owns the Bar (`bar`) that's calling the function (`x`).  This works, but my Eclipse warns me that "foo may not have been initialized", referencing the call to `doStuff();` -- because, when the engine first sees the line, we haven't finished defining `foo` yet.  Of course, `x()` can't be called unless `foo` is constructed successfully, but my style checker apparently hasn't figured that out.

So I'm at a loss for how to deal with this.  Should I ignore the warning?  Is there a way to mark it as such, so I don't get a warning anymore?  Am I doing this wrong?  Should I pass my reference in a different manner?

Comment: Is that a typo? Should it be `doStuff(foo)` instead of `doStuff(f)`

Comment: Don't use eclipse. There are better IDEs (WebStorm 3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var Foo = function() { }

var Bar = function (obj) {
  // foo is not initialized
  obj.x();
  // called doStuff with undefined
}

var foo = new Foo({
  bar: new Bar({
    x: function(){
      doStuff(foo);
    }
  });
});
```

Eclipse is right. Again if you want a better analysis system consider using WebStorm 3.0 or Visual Studio 11 as your JS IDE.

Comment: I understand why it's complaining.  I'm just 99% sure that there's no *actual* execution context in which `x()` can be **invoked** while `foo` remains undefined.  Yes, the `Bar` constructor will complete before the `Foo` constructor completes, but it's not as though anything can *act* on the `Bar` object that's created (and assigned to `foo.bar`) until after the `Foo` object is fully constructed, at which point the `foo` variable is initialized.  If that makes any sense...

Comment: aside: VS is not an option (though I'm generally a fan...) since I'm developing in Linux.  I'll take a serious look at WebStorm -- thanks for the pointer!

Comment: @Coderer I just showed you a context where x is called when foo is undefined

Comment: OK, I'm still newb enough at JavaScript that I had to re-read that about a dozen times before it clicked.  You're saying, if Bar's constructor **calls its own `x` method**, during construction (!!!), that the method will try to use `foo`, which isn't defined.  Totally makes sense now.  Is there a pattern to prevent this from happening? I can't think of one.

Comment: @Coderer it's called don't reference yourself in your declaration. It's bad practice to do so, (unless it's a simple declaration like a function)

Comment: good to know -- is there a "right" way to say "give me a reference to the object that owns me", like in the circumstance I describe in the OP?

Comment: @Coderer look at your code, Bar depends on Foo and Foo depends on Bar. Cirular dependencies like that are always evil.

Comment: So I agree with the sentiment, but this is for a UI.  Replace "Foo" with "Dialog" and "Bar" with "Button" -- the dialog has a button, and when I click on the button, it has to "do stuff" with its parent dialog.  Is there a better design for that?

Comment: @Coderer [Example](https://gist.github.com/1331240). Create the objects, then create the link between the objects later with a decently named linking method.

Answer (score 1):

It's nothing to do with javascript, but probably something to do with Eclipse. The variable *foo* can be declared anywhere, since variable declarations are processed before any code is executed. It can also be initialised at any time before *doStuff* is called (though initialising variables without declaring them is considered bad form).

Answer (score 0):

First, a Foo is constructed. To its constructor, a new Bar is passed, which is passed a function using a variable foo.

But foo is only assigned a value after the constructor of Foo is finished. At that point, the function is already declared, using the undeclared variable foo.
If the function is used in the constructor of either Bar or Foo, it will fail.

Comment: First, `foo` is created as a property of the local variable object. The code seems to be in the global scope so it is a property of the global object (a global variable) before any code is executed. When *doStuff* is called, *foo* exists, but might not have been assigned a value (i.e. it might be undefined).

Comment: Are you suggesting that the OP's code will throw an error? Because it won't.

Comment: I'm not suggesting that, I'm explaining how it is possible that the variable is not assigned at the moment doStuff is called. I'm not saying that it is, but it is possible, therefor the warning is issued. Whether `foo` is declared as a property or as a global doesn't really matter in this situation. The simplest way to prevent the warning, is to assign a value (can be null) to `foo` before calling this assignment.

Answer (score 0):

I think @RobG is right, that this is an Eclipse issue and it's probably best just to deal with it. But if you wanted to avoid it, you can declare `foo` before you initialize it, and I bet this will keep Eclipse from complaining:

```
var foo;
foo = new Foo({
  bar: new Bar({
    x: function(){
      doStuff(foo);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Just declaring it isn't good enough (it's declared, but still not technically "initialized"), and I have a hard time bringing myself to do something like `var foo = "some garbage"; foo = new Foo(....);`

Comment: Yeah, you could initialize it to `null`, but at that point your screwing up your coding style to fit your IDE, which is no good.

Comment: Javascript doesn't require variables to be assigned a value (initialised), so it's just Eclipse being picky. Run your code through jslint and see what you get!!

Comment: I intend to try JSLint, but it's so picky it's going to take me hours to fix all its warnings, so I wanted to try to work with the "lenient" warnings in Eclipse first.  I know the values don't *have* to be initialized, but there's value in making you think about what could go wrong (like if initializing code is inside a conditional)